# Where is the cast in this code?

Tags: c++, qt, casting, clang

I have some lines of my code which returns an error from our static code analyzer.

This analyzer is programmed with clang, and the source code of the rule that is violated is quite simple :

```
// For each cast expression in the code 
bool VisitCastExpr(CastExpr *castExpr){
    string errorMsg;
    string CastName = castExpr->getCastKindName();
    // If cast is from pointer to everything different than an integer, add violation 
    if((castExpr->getCastKind() == CK_MemberPointerToBoolean)||(castExpr->getCastKind() == CK_PointerToBoolean)||(castExpr->getCastKind() == CK_CPointerToObjCPointerCast)||(castExpr->getCastKind() == CK_BlockPointerToObjCPointerCast)||(castExpr->getCastKind() == CK_AnyPointerToBlockPointerCast)){
        errorMsg = "Forbidden cast "+CastName+" from pointer to non-integer type";
        addViolation(castExpr,this,errorMsg);
    }
    return true; 
}
```

So basically, it just adds a violation when some cast (implicit or explicit) is done from pointer to something different than integer.

Here is one of the expressions that returns an error :

`if(st_parametre_embarque.qs_nom.contains("PAR")){`.

`st_parametre_embarque` is just a structure, and the field `qs_nom` is a `QString`.

Method [Qstring::contains()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#contains) does return a boolean.

Here is the violation message yielded by the code analyzer :

**Forbidden cast PointerToBoolean from pointer to non-integer type**

So I really don't see where there could be any `castExpr`, moreover from **pointer** to boolean.

Comment: Um, `"PAR"`? It decays to `const char*`...

Comment: Yes, but look at the declaration of `contains` method, we want a Qstring as parameter. Even if there is some cast from `const char *` to `QString`, it will never be from pointer to boolean, will it ?

Comment: What's the error message (the one your code construct) when it encounters this line?

Comment: You should check which one of the `castExpr->getCastKind() == ...` expressions evaluates to true. Maybe you can get some details from problematic `castExpr` besides `getCastKind()`.

Comment: @AntonSavin : I know which one is evaluated to True, it is `CK_PointerToBoolean`, since I am getting it as a string (`string CastName = castExpr->getCastKindName();`)

Comment: @JBL : Forbidden cast PointerToBoolean from pointer to non-integer type

Comment: Have you tried `if(st_parametre_embarque.qs_nom.contains(QString("PAR"))){`? Also does the `CastExpr` provide information about the pointer type being cast?

Comment: You could try to break up the offending expression to isolate the problem: `auto&& part1 = st_parametre_embarque.qs_nom; auto&& part2 = part1.contains("PAR"); if (part2) {` (on separate lines, to ease location). Are you also 100% certain that it's reporting it in the correct place? E.g. could it be reporting a violation inside the `{}` at the line of the `if`?

Comment: @AntonSavin : returns the same error. I don't have any information about the pointer. 
@Angew : I'm 100% sure it is occuring in the `if` condition.

Comment: @Angew : I broke up the expression in 2 parts as you suggested. The violation comes from the second part : `bool some_bool = part1.contains("PAR");`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you send a wide-string, I.e. `L"PAR"` ?

Comment: Can you break it up more: `QString par("PAR"); bool some_bool = part1.contains(par);`?

Comment: And which one is it with even more breaking up, `QString s("PAR"); bool some_bool = part1.contains(s);`? Also, is there a chance the analyser would actually be picking up a violation inside an `inline` function of `QString` itself?

Comment: @WhozCraig : What do you mean sending a wide-string, to `contains()` method ?

Comment: @AntonSavin, @Angew : Error occurs on the `bool some_bool = name.contains(par);` line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before Qt5, `QString::contains` returned a `QBool`, not a `bool`. That value has to be converted to a bool somehow, and the static analyzer has decided it's an implicit cast. Try making an explicit comparison with a boolean constant (i.e. invoking `operator==(QBool, bool)`) and see if the static analyzer follows it.

Comment: Can you provide a proof that `contains` returns a `QBool` ?? 

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#contains says that it returns a simple bool.

Comment: Line 195 of https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/5dc8b2bac4657827293cfc870ba49fa87ec96e13:src/corelib/tools/qstring.h

Comment: Note: QBool was removed in Qt5, it's now a simple bool ([doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/sourcebreaks.html), [5.3 source](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/1498c99e9d5fac758bd9372e199366059af81a6f:src/corelib/tools/qstring.h#L318)).